# FAQ Section on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, badges

I am not able to figure out which is FAQ section on Stack Overflow? I have visited various sections but still don't get the badge `Analytical`, means I have not yet visited FAQ section.

Can you please assist me where to find it?

I am new on this site please forgive me if my question is wrong.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The FAQ no longer exists and you can no longer earn the Analytical badge, hence the "(retired)" at the end of the description.

It was replaced by the [tour page](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) which will earn you the Informed badge for reading.

Comment: So why till `Analytical` badge present in badges section? it confusing me

Comment: Because they don't like taking badges away from people who had earned them previously. That's why they marked it as retired, to indicate that it is a remnant of the past and can no longer be earned.

Comment: One person got their `Analytical` badge yesterday. How is that so?

Comment: @PythonMaster Account merges. If you previously had it and your accounts get merged together, it will re-award it to you. That's the only possible way.